# How do negative operands to bitwise operators work in Java?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
-4 & -5 = -8 // How?
-4 & 5 = 4 // How?
```

I need an explanation for how the above results can be reached. I have no difficulties in solving with positive integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do bitwise operator results occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169287/how-do-bitwise-operator-results-occur)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just convert the integers to their binary representation (for negative integers, use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)) and run the bit-wise AND:

```
-4 11111..1100 &
-5 11111..1011

-8 11111..1000


-4 11111..1100 &
 5 00000..0101

 4 00000..0100
```

Comment: i too tried with 2's complement for -ve integers but i don't understand why i didn't get the right answer until i saw your's :(

Comment: @divine The way to find 2's complement of a positive `int` i is to calculate 2^32-i. 2^32 is 10000..000 (1 followed by 32 0s). If you subtract from it 4 (100), you get 1111...11100 (30 1s followed by 2 0s), which is the binary representation of -4.

Comment: Other ways to find the 2's complements. 1) Not and then increment: 2) Write down, from LSb, all the zeros until the first one included, then write the rest of the bits complemented.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see how numbers are representing:

```
positive four    0100          
negative four    1100
positive five    0101          
negative five    1011
negative eight   1000
```

If you try to do `and` operation manual, you get a result like this:

```
1100 (-4) & 1011 (-5) = 1000 (-8)
1100 (-4) & 0101 (5) = 0100 (4)
```

[Here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-2/negative-binary-numbers/) you can read more about this.